# The last of the objects in the array that have the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
const obj = [
{
    id:1,
    info : [
        {
            status:"open",
            value:300
        },
        {
            status:"closed",
            value:1
        },
        {
            status:"open",
            value:100
        }
    ]
},
{
    id:2,
    info : [
        {
            status:"open",
            value:40
        },
        {
            status:"closed",
            value:1
        },
        {
            status:"open",
            value:150
        },
        {
            status:"open",
            value:250
        },
        {
            status:"closed",
            value:10
        }
    ]
}
]
```

What I want to do is filter by the value of the last one whose status is open.

For example, if I want to find values greater than 200, it should only return me with an id of 2. Because the last status value of the object whose id is 2 is 250.

I tried something like this, but the status is filtering by all that are open.

```
const filtered = obj.filter(o => {
  return o.info.find(value => {
    if (value.status == "open") {
      if(value.value > 200){
      return true;
    }
  };
 });
});
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the logic you want to implement. The code in your question produces a result array containing only the object with an ID of 2. Was that what you wanted? If so, might you show an example where your code *doesn't* produce what you want? (Your code makes sense but I don't understand the English)

Comment: I updated the first open value with an id of 1. now my code will return both id 1 and 2. But it should only return with id of 2.
Because the value of its last open state is 250.

Comment: Filtering by the latest of the open statuses

Comment: If you don't care about performance (not as indictment, but because perf almost certainly just doesn't matter here), any reason not to use `.reverse().find(e => ...)`? Because that'll find the first entry that matches whatever you need. And if you do care about performance, then just use a reverse for loop (`for (let i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--) { ... }`) and break on the first hit.

Comment: There may be an important situation for performance, a much more effective method. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const filtered = obj.filter(o => {
  for (let i = o.info.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (o.info[i].status === 'open') {
      return o.info[i].value > 200
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last "open" record, by executing `find()` after [reversing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  info: [
    { status: "open", value: 20 }, 
    { status: "closed", value: 1 },
    { status: "open", value: 100 }
  ]
}, {
  id: 2,
  info: [
    { status: "open", value: 40 },
    { status: "closed", value: 1 },
    { status: "open", value: 150 },
    { status: "open", value: 250 },
    { status: "closed", value: 10 }
  ]
}];

const fn = (data, value) => data.filter(
  ({info}) => [...info.reverse()].find(
    ({status}) => status === 'open'
  )?.value > value
).map(({id}) => id);

console.log(fn(data, 200));
```

Note that `reverse()` changes the array in place. To avoid the original data being modified, I spread the array into a new array.

Comment: reverse had never occurred to me. Thank you, nice solution.